# SendEmail in hidden or minimized

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, alert

I use [SendEmail.exe](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) to send automatic emails using Windows Task Scheduler

[image]

But when it does launch that SendEmail.exe it launches in a command prompt shown below which is shown on the screen for few seconds
[image]

Is there any way to minimize this or hide it completely?

***Reason***
I have sendEmail Enabled as an action when somebody RDPs to my server so them knowing that i am sending an alert defeats the purpose of this alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the General Page select "Run whether user is logged on or not" and select "Hidden".

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the process, a little more detail, might make this more helpful to people.

Comment: Yeah. Now I see that it was not enough details. I should have thought about others too, not only the poster of the question.

Comment: Thanks, this does work but i am getting 10 emails for every login, Debuggin that now. I like this solution, simpler

Comment: it's flooding my inbox got 65 or so emails so far

Comment: if i check "Run whether user is logged on or not" then i get duplicate emails

Comment: if i do not check "Run whether user is logged on or not" then the popup is still visible even with the hidden checked

Comment: What have you set as trigger?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of launching SendEmail.exe directly in the task, launch `Start` with SendEmail as an argument.  That way you can then take advantage of Start's ability to run minimized.

From `Start /?`:

```
MIN         Start window minimized.
```

So change the "Program/Script" to `start` and then add `"" /Min "c:\sendEmail-v156\sendemail.exe" <your arguments for SendEmail>` in the "Add arguments (optional)" field.

Comment: Thank you will try that. never thought about it. i kept trying /min in arguments. glad i asked

Comment: from command prompt start "" /Min "c:\sendEmail-v156\sendemail.exe" <your arguments for SendEmail> this works and it minimizes the popup too but when i put start in program and rest in Add arguments this it doen'st work. It's like it's not liking the start being a program